# Ĉu oni aldonu -n finaĵon al tagoj por indiki okazaĵojn en tiuj tagoj?

Tags: word-usage

> Ŝia naskiĝtago okazos la duan de februaro.

1. Kial oni aldonas -n finaĵon al la vorto "dua"? Kion sifnifas la frazo sen tiu -n finaĵo?
2. Ĉu oni ankaŭ povas diri tion tiel: "Ŝia naskiĝtago okazos en la dua de februaro." ?

Comment: Bonvolu legi https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/rolmontriloj/n/tempopunkto.html Tie vi trovos la klarigon por la `-n` kaj ankaŭ samsignifajn konstruojn sen ĝi.

Comment: Koran dankon, Sinjoro @EduardoTrápani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Por indiki, ke temas pri tempo kaj ne simpla subjekto. Komparu la jenajn frazojn:

   i. Lundon estas festo.

   ii. Lundo estas festo.

   La unua frazo signifas, ke en lundo (unu specifa tago) okazos iu festo. La dua frazo signifas, ke lundo (la ĝenerala tago de la semajno) estas konsiderata kiel festo.
   Do tiel ni uzas la n-finaĵon por distingigi tempomomenton disde la koncepto de la tago.

   Via frazo kun ‘dua’ anstataŭ ‘duan’ estas gramatike malĝusta kaj ne havas sencon.
2. Jes, tio estas tute ĝusta.

Comment: Dankon Sinjor(in)o @Joffysloffy pro via helpo.

Comment: @Qàtrè Nedankinde; mi ĝojas, ke mi povis helpi!